# How to run multiple jobs from a single job in TALEND

Tags: data-migration, talend

I have multiple jobs of TALEND. Now i want to create a single job from which i can trigger all other jobs and also need to put some check that if one job fails then other jobs should not run. Is it possible in TALEND. Someone please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create another wrapper job and in this job drag and drop all other jobs you want to run..tRunJob component will be used..and you can set dependencies between these jobs...

Comment: could you please guide me how to use tRunJob?..i mean how to map other jobs with it..

Comment: just create a new blank job, and from the repository on left hand side pane, simply drag the jobs you want to run inside this job..one by one, and then you can select any of these dragged job and go to component property and you can see many things there..also if  you right click on these you can add on job ok/other triggers to other jobs..or you can simply drag and drop tRunjob component and in its properties select the job you want to run..just try it out, you will figure it out

Comment: Thanks...i just drop all my jobs and on right click on a particular job-->Trigger-->OnSubJobOk-->then linked it with second job and so on...it worked like a charm...:)